# CasperJS - using jQuery. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery/$

Tags: javascript, jquery, cmd, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm writing code that involves jQuery in CasperJS. By chance, could someone point out the error I've made in including jQuery? (After 45 minutes of searching, I'm starting to think it's a local problem.)

I have tried both of the following:

```
casper.page.injectJs('C:\sweeps\jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
```

and

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
clientScripts: ["C:\sweeps\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
});
```

**Code:**

```
// sample.js
var casper = require('casper').create();

var login = "some username"; 
var password = "some password";

casper.start('https://www.paypal.com/us/home', function() {
    this.fillXPath('form.login', {
        '//input[@name="login_email"]':    login,
        '//input[@name="login_password"]':    password,
    }, true);
});

casper.page.injectJs('C:\sweeps\jquery-1.10.2.min.js');

$("input[name='submit.x']").click();

   setTimeout(function(){ 
   setTimeout(function(){ 

casper.run(function() {

this.captureSelector('example2.png', '#page');

    this.echo('Done.').exit();

});

}, 30000); }, 1);
```

**Output:**

```
ReferenceError: Can't find cariable: jQuery
C:/sweeps/test2.js:21
```

The same result comes when "jQuery" is switched to "$".

EDIT: I've also tried relative pathing.

My reference is: [Can I use jQuery with CasperJS?](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs)

Comment: `/path/to/jquery.js` is a relative path. As general rule don't use absolute paths.

Comment: Sorry didnt include that ive tried relative. I saw a recommendation on a google thread to try it. I tried relative and it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [Casper#evaluate()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)

> The concept behind this method is probably the most difficult to understand when discovering CasperJS. As a reminder, think of the evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
    $("input[name='submit.x']").click();
});
```

You need to use the jQuery selector as if you were in a browser.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks. You're right. Very explanatory. Thank you for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the javascript file should be a URI relative to your HTML file, not a file-system path. Assuming your files are in the c:\sweepstakes folder, try

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  clientScripts: ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
});
```

Also, use your browser's network/dev tools to see if your jQuery library is being downloaded or not.

Comment: I wasnt using the jquery properly. I have to use the .evaluate.
I had previously tested this but forgot to put it in the description. I editted it. Thank you.